# KMutableProperty with <A,B> and <A,B?>

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I want to pass a KMutableProperty1 to a constructor. The problem is that sometimes I need to pass property like this:

```
class Foo(var name:String, var email:String?)

class PropertyHandler<D,F>(val prop:KMutableProperty1<D,F>)

fun test() {
   val foo = Foo("Asd", "asd@asd.com")
   val ph1 = PropertyHandler<Foo,String>(Foo::name)
   val ph2 = PropertyHandler<Foo,String>(Foo::email)
}
```

At this case compiler said at PropertyHandler(Foo::email) :

```
Required KMutableProperty1<Foo,String?>
Found KMutableProperty1<Foo,String>
```

Is there a method to pass String & String? to this?

I use it in Android, and my Kotlin version is 1.3.50

thx
Zamek

Comment: [I didn't reproduce it on Kotlin JVM 1.3.61](https://pl.kotl.in/RMJ4q628A) (assuming that `Foo` is `class Foo(var name: String, var email: String?)`.

Comment: I checked it with kotlin 1.3.61 but of course same result

Comment: You have edited your question. The new version of the code doesn't compile, check out my answer to see how you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

By writing `PropertyHandler<Foo, String>(Foo::email)`, you explicitly specify that `D` is `Foo`, and `F` is `String`. So `prop` should be `KMutableProperty1<Foo, String>`. But `Foo::email` is `KMutableProperty1<Foo, String?>`. And `KMutableProperty1<Foo, String>` isn't assignable from `KMutableProperty1<Foo, String?>` since `KMutableProperty1<T, R>` is invariant to its second generic parameter. Therefore, you get a compilation error.

Here are a few ways of fixing your code:

1. Replace `PropertyHandler<Foo, String>(Foo::email)` with `PropertyHandler<Foo, String?>(Foo::email)`
2. Make `PropertyHandler<D, F>` constructor accept `KMutableProperty1<D, in F>`

   ```
   class PropertyHandler<D, F>(val prop: KMutableProperty1<D, in F>)
   ```
3. Make `email` not nullable

   ```
   class Foo(var name: String, var email: String)
   ```
4. Perform an unchecked cast (not recommended)

   ```
   @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") // explain here why it is safe
   PropertyHandler<Foo, String>(Foo::email as KMutableProperty1<Foo, String>)
   ```